# Can’t open a file whose directory’s name starting with #

Tags: vim, vi

I am using gvim on Windows10.

I use gvim as a default text editor on my PC.

When I double click and open a .txt file which is in a directory starting with “#”

For example:

`C:first/second/#third/text.txt`

Then gvim opens up and throws E344.
It seems accessing a wrong directory:

`C:first/second#third/text.txt`

How can I avoid this error without changing the name of the directory?

Comment: vim is treating `/` as escape character for `#`. Use `//#` in the path

Comment: This might not be right to ask but how can I set my vim to work like that?  I double click the file and my vim seems to automatically follow the path with just single slashes.